# How to select all the rows and still select distinct rows?

Tags: vb.net

In the below code how would I select all coloumn values but also select distinct rows by first name? Customer is a datatable and it has two fields. Id and First Name. If I try that I get distinct rows back, but I'm not getting id coloumn back.

```
Customer.DefaultView.ToTable(True, {"FirstName"})
```

If I try this, it tries to do a distinct by id and first name so results are duplicated

```
Customer.DefaultView.ToTable(True, {"FirstName", "ID"})
```

Comment: Which ID value do you want back when getting the distinct values (max, min for example)?

Comment: I want ID and FirstName to be returned. ID is a primary key. I want to show distinct FirstNames with their corresponding ID's.

Comment: Sound like you want to list IDs but Grouped By FirstName to give something like 1 John, 5 John, 2 Mike, 9 Nigel, 12 Nigel, 23 Nigel, 18 Roger....

Comment: @Yeswanth Assume you have: `{ Kalle, 1}, {Kalle, 2}, {Kalle, 4}` You want to return a single `Kalle` and which `ID`?

Comment: @Magnus I understand what you are saying now. The first id in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
Customer.AsEnumerable()
     .GroupBy(function(x) x.Field(Of String)("FirstName"))
     .Select(function(x) New With 
     {
         .FirstName = x.Key.Field(Of String)("FirstName"), 
         .ID = x.Min(function(y) y.Field(Of Integer)("ID"))
     });
```